# Подключение к удаленному серверу через программу на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, сервер, вконтакте, скрипт

Есть у меня сервер на Linux с простеньким чат-ботом вк, написанным на Python. Можно ли как-нибудь организовать доступ к серверу c винды через программку с графическим интерфейсом (которая тоже, например, на Python) для настройки и управления этим самым ботом (по типу: нажал на кнопку - запустился файл с питоновским скриптом на серве и тд.). Если да, то что для этого нужно? Или всё же лучше использовать более подходящее решение, нежели питон?

Comment: Можно конечно. Пишите серверную часть, пишите клиентскую часть. Они взаимодействуют друг с другом через сокеты / HTTP-запросы.

Comment: @nightflash понял, спасибо за помощь)